# Does iCloud Passwords enable access to iCloud Keychain passwords?

Tags: icloud

As a MacOS user, I enjoy the native password manager (iCloud Keychain), however, sometimes it is necessary to hop on a Windows browser.

Does iCloud passwords sync passwords from Keychain?  Ideally, the answer would be yes.

Please to start the answer with a Yes or No.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The iCloud Passwords extension exposes iCloud-synced passwords to Chrome and Edge.

Passwords you save on your Mac to the "Passwords" section in Safari or in System Settings will be synced to iCloud Keychain if you enable "Passwords & Keychain" in iCloud settings.

Comment: You could add the Apple links regarding iCloud passwords on Windows. https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/icloud-windows/icw2babf5e03/icloud https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/icloud-windows/icwa812f1681/1.0/icloud/1.0